# maven wsdl2code generating improper java stub file

Tags: maven

I am using Maven which generates an improper java stub file since not generating 
    xmlns:t=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512\" 
on the appropriate lines in the java stub file.
I am new to this, but below is the snippet I am using.
Wondering if adb vs xmlbeans is a possible issue?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
<artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6.2</version> <!-- do not want to change since rebuilding existing webapp -->
<configuration>
<wsdlFile>src/main/resource/wsdl/wsdlfile.wsdl</wsdlFile>
<databindingName>adb</databindingName> 
<packageName>com.vendorproduct.ws.wsdl</packageName>
<outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
<unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
<unwrap>true</unwrap>
<syncMode>sync</syncMode>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>wsdl2code</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Unable to provide generated code snipped since need 10 reputation points to post more than 2 links, But the problem is the generated code is missing xmlns:t=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512\" and so get runtime error 'undeclared namespace prefix "t"'.

Trying using jaxws-maven-plugin (snip below), but get:
Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.1:wsimport (wsdla) on project vendorproduct: Error executing: wsimport [-s, H:\Folder\src\main\java\src, -d, H:\Folder\target\classes, -verbose, -p, com.vendorproduct, -Xnocompile, H:\Folder\src\main\resources\filename.wsdl]

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>wsdla</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>wsimport</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<packageName>com.vendorproduct</packageName>
<sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
<wsdlFiles>
<wsdlFile>
${basedir}/src/main/resources/filename.wsdl
</wsdlFile>
</wsdlFiles>
<bindingDirectory> <!-- Is this only used for generation output? -->
${basedir}/src/wsdl/binding
</bindingDirectory>
<verbose>true</verbose>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Going back to axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin and trying xmlbeans for databindingname, but get compile error: (believe have all axis2 dependencies including axiom-api-1.2.13 and axiom-impl-1.2.13)
no suitable method found for toEnvelope(org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory,com.rightnow.ws.messages.GetMetaDataDocument,boolean)
    method com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.toEnvelope(org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory,org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString,org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString,com.rightnow.ws.messages.GetValuesForNamedIDDocument,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Even though have the compile error, it did generate the Stub file in the same improper way without the xmlns:t.

Switching back to using adb.
I verified using maven 3.5.0 and tried 'mvn package' on command line, but generating the Stub file in the same improper way without the xmlns:t.

Axis2 Developer Mailing List says Axis2 1.6.2 is over 5 years old and is not supported.
Will have to rework the 'old' source code to use a recent (and supported) version of Axis2.
Is Axis2 1.7.5 the best choice?

Comment: Can you show what it generates?

Comment: (__operation).getMessage(org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE).getPolicySubject().attachPolicy(getPolicy("<wsp:Policy wsu:Id=\"FedAuthSyncPolicy\" xmlns:wsp=\"http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702\"> MISSING xmlns:t HERE <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp=\"http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy\"> and so on.

Comment: Any particular reason that you're using the `axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin`? Have you considered using the [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) instead?

Comment: Will try jaxws-maven-plugin instead. Thank You Steve.

Comment: Prefer to stick with axis2 as this was used in original ANT build which I have inherited.

Comment: The vendor wsdl has namespace t in the line <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp='http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' wsu:Id='FedAuthSyncPolicy' xmlns:wsam='http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata' xmlns:sp='http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702' xmlns:t='http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512' xmlns:wsaw='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' xmlns:wsx='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex'>
   <wsp:ExactlyOne> - why wsdl2code is not generating xmlns:t and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The source of this issue was using Axis2 1.6.2.
Axis2 Developer Mailing List says Axis2 1.6.2 is over 5 years old and is not supported.